# bash for-loop in script won't run as non-root cron script

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, cron

I have a cron script that I run nightly from the system-wide /etc/crontab like this:

```
00 01 * * * www-data /root/scripts/image-auto-process.sh 1> /var/data/logs/cron.out 2> /var/data/logs/cron.err
```

It's a bash script that backs up (with rsync) some directories full of scanned jpegs, runs a php-program to batch process those jpegs (preview/thumbnails), uploads them to a server and upon success cleans out the first mentioned directories.
Everything but the last clean-out step works like a charm. However, if I run it from the commandline as the www-data user, it works. When it runs via cron as same user, it doesn't.

The last, clean-out step looks like the following:

```
echo "remove original scans"
for i in `find $SCAN_ORIG_DIR -mindepth 2 -type d -print | grep -v -f $EXCLUDES`; do rm -rvf $i; done
echo "job Done..."
```

`$SCAN_ORIG_DIR` is the directory to search. `$EXCLUDES` is a file (readable to www-data) containing lines with directories to ignore (same file is used to tell rsync what *not* to backup). -mindepth 2 is used in find because I only want to return subdir's of `$SCAN_ORIG_DIR` that also have subdirs, like `$SCAN_ORIG_DIR/subdir/subsubdir`.

I tried putting the above code into its own script and running it on commandline and via cron just to make sure no prior code in the script was causing the problem.
Results in commandline (not exact representation, but just to illustrate):

```
remove original scans
removed '$SCAN_ORIG_DIR/subdir1/subsubdir'
removed '$SCAN_ORIG_DIR/subdir2/subsubdir'
removed '$SCAN_ORIG_DIR/subdir3/subsubdir'
job Done...
```

Results via cron:

```
remove original scans
job Done...
```

So, I'm stumped. I sincerely hope anyone can help shine a light on what's wrong here.
Thank you very much for you time and efforts :-)

Comment: The symptoms suggest empty output from the backticks. Maybe you can add a few debug statements to your script to see where exactly it's going wrong. The lack of quoting might be a problem, or cron gets a version of grep which has some issue with the filter file. It is a well known caveat that cron jobs get a different environment than interactive scripts.

Comment: How/where do you set `$SCAN_ORIG_DIR`? Also you can try `sudo -u www-data sh /root/scripts/image-auto-process.sh ...`. Are you sure the script is executable by www-data?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Its set at top of script like: `SCAN_ORIG_DIR="/mnt/imageserver/scan/orig/Scan"`. Yes I'm sure script is executable by www-data since I've seen it run.

Comment: Does root have read access to that directory? If it's a network mounted directory, this is not always a given.

Comment: @triplee: I added echo statements inside for-loop and they showed up when run on commandline, but not via cron. Yes I think you're probably correct about cron job getting different environment. I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @l0b0: its a samba mount but everything in there is 777 (because of problems with Windows clients I guess) so everyone + dog can read/write there ;-)

Comment: @triplee: re environment, the crontab has these: `SHELL=/bin/sh` which points to bash, `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`. `whereis grep` yields: `grep: /bin/grep` so it looks like env is all good... (unless I'm missing something obvious).

Comment: When bash is invoked as "sh", you don't get all the capabilities of bash. Check the man page under Invocation

Comment: Also, instead of (or in addition to) adding `echo`s you can turn on tracing with `set -x`.

Comment: What's the output of `find $SCAN_ORIG_DIR -mindepth 2 -type d -print | grep -v -f $EXCLUDES` and just the `find`?

Comment: @glenn jackman: I changed crontab's `SHELL=/bin/sh` to `SHELL=/bin/bash` but still same problem - for-loop just won't run. I changed backticks around the find|grep part like `FOUND=$(find|grep)` and then looped over `$FOUND` instead. Nope, no go. Script that is being triggered is also `#!/bin/bash` just to make sure the script was running through bash.

Comment: I think you could use: `find $SCAN_ORIG_DIR -mindepth 2 -type d -print | grep -v -f $EXCLUDES | xargs rm -rvf ` instead of the for loop

Comment: @ydroneaud: tried that too. That's why I ended up trying the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem with scripts when running in cron, is that the user login scripts (.bashrc, ,bash_profile) are not executed, so some variables are missing.

BTW, it is not good practice to use the system-wide /etc/crontab. Use crontab -e to add cron jobs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I'll look into whether the missing invocation of `.bashrc` etc. impacts the script when run as cron. I've used the system-wide crontab to keep things in one central location and avoid having crontab's spread all over the filesystem. Sometimes I've been thinking "where the #!@% does that job get run from" ;-)